# infinite do while loop?

Tags: java, loops

I want to make a loop that will print wrong answer each time answer is not 1 2 3 or 4 ....
and I want it to run infinitly, mine don't detect if the answer is right or wrong it just print out invalid answer, then asks again, then crash! I don't know why it does that.

Here's my code don't read the "text" part because it's in French just look a the code!

```
System.out.println("Veuillez Choisir 1 des 4 groupes alimentaires suivants: (1)Légumes et fruits , (2) Produit cérealiers , (3) Laits et Substitues , (4) Viandes et substitues :");
        System.out.println("\n");
    answer =  Clavier.lireIntLn();
    do {
        System.out.println("Votre choix est invalide");
         System.out.println("Veuillez Choisir 1 des 4 groupes alimentaires suivants: (1)Légumes et fruits , (2) Produit cérealiers , (3) Laits et Substitues , (4) Viandes et substitues :");
            answer =  Clavier.lireIntLn();
                continue;
        }while (answer<1 && answer>5);
```

Comment: Remove the `continue`

Comment: I dont understand how a developer can use a `do-while` or `continue` is something awful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to remove the `continue`.

After you do that, you will need to deal with this:

```
while (answer<1 && answer>5)
```

This will never happen. You need to do this:

```
while (answer<1 || answer>5)
```

You can't have a number be less than 1 AND greater than 5.

Answer (score 1):

The `continue` statement causes the program execution to jump back to `do` immediately without even evaluate the while-condition. That means the condition is never evaluated and the loop becomes infinite.

Remove the continue, and the loop will be left when the while-condition is false. Unfortunately it will always be false, because a value can't be below 1 **and** above 5. When you want to continue until the user inputs 5, then try

```
while (answer != 5)
```

When you want (as written) allow any answer except 1, 2, 3 or 4, do this

```
while(answer >= 1 && answer <= 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code would be more like this:

```
do
{
    System.out.println("Veuillez Choisir 1 des 4 groupes alimentaires suivants: (1)Légumes et fruits , (2) Produit cérealiers , (3) Laits et Substitues , (4) Viandes et substitues :");
    System.out.println("\n");
    answer =  Clavier.lireIntLn();
    if( answer < 1 || answer > 4  )
    {
        //print your error message here
    }
}while(true)
```

Comment: ".. and i want it to run infinitly"

Answer (score 0):

The continue prevents it from reaching the while statement. Remove it and it will hit the while condition.